# How to inject unevaluated list of Unique into a RuleDelayed?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, hold

I am writing a function that constructs a rule which has `Unique[]` in the RHS.  Here is a simplified segment of code

```
$userInt = 3;

With[{x = Table[Unique[], {i, 1, 3}]},
  rules = {patt :> x}
]
```

Here, `rules` should be look like a list of `Unique[]`, as in

`patt :> {Unique[], Unique[], ...}`

But the problem is that `Unique[]` is already evaluated by the `With`:

```
rules

(* {patt :> {$48, $48, $48}} *)
```

How can I generate a list of `Unique[]` that is not evaluated, but evaluated when it is time to pattern match?

Comment: I messed up the code a bit.  The upper limit of the `Table` iterator should be `$userInt`, not harded-coded `3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
With[{x = Table[HoldForm@Unique[], {i, 1, 3}]}, rules = {patt :> x}]
```

[image]

```
patt /. (ReleaseHold@rules)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This can be a good case for a `Block` trick:

```
Block[{Unique},
  With[{x = Table[Unique[], {i, 1, 3}]}, rules = {patt :> x}]
]

(* {patt :> {Unique[], Unique[], Unique[]}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$userInt = 5;

With[{
  x = Table[Inactive@Unique[], {i, $userInt}]
  }, 
   rules = {_Integer :> x} // Activate
]
```

> ```
> {_Integer :> {Unique[], Unique[], Unique[], Unique[], Unique[]}}
> ```

```
{1} /. rules
```

> ```
> {{$27, $28, $29, $30, $31}}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

So many ways:

```
Apply[Unique, (patt :> #) & @ Table[{}, {3}], {2}]

(patt :> Evaluate@Table[foo[], {3}]) /. foo -> Unique

Hold[Unique[]][[Range[3]^0]] /. _[x__] :> (patt :> {x})

(patt :> {##}) & @@ Table[Unevaluated @ Unevaluated @ Unique[], {3}]

(Function @@ {patt :> Evaluate@Table[#[], {3}]}) @ Unique
```

All produce:

> ```
> patt :> {Unique[], Unique[], Unique[]}
> ```

But I must say I don't see why you wouldn't just use:

```
rule = patt :> Table[Unique[], {3}];

patt /. rule
patt /. rule
```

> ```
> {$3, $4, $5}
>
> {$6, $7, $8}
> ```